# Spark word-Listof items program

Tags: scala, apache-spark, word-count

Wordcount program is easy, but how to get word list of items based on key.(Not number of count)
Let eg:
Location, Items
Bangalore,TV
Bangalore,Mobile
Hyderabad,Laptop

Now I need output like this:
Bangalore, (TV, Mobile)
Hyderabad, Laptop
It may Json or csv or any format.

Comment: @RaduIonescu, yep, and OP should consult pretty much any Spark tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

Cityitems.csv:
City,Items
Bangalore,Mobile
Bangalore,Laptop
Bangalore,Mobile
Bangalore,Desktop
Hyderabad,Cooker
    val data=sc.textFile("s3://path/Cityitems.csv").cache()
    val rows = data.map(line => line.split(","))

```
val makestructure = rows.map(name => (name(0),name(1)))

makestructure.groupByKey.collect.foreach(println)
```